# How to assign variable value to an object property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Consider this example: `var v = 4; canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = v;`. I then change the value of **v**, and run `canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = v;` again. The brush width changes as intended, however, it causes lots of bugs where some drawn paths are shifted or are partially erased. What am I doing wrong? Is it even allowed to initialize an objects property through a variable? (I am using fabric.js library).

EDIT: My original function looks like this:

```js
switch (thickness) {
    case "small-thickness":
        v = smallThickness;
        break;
    case "medium-thickness":
        v = mediumThickness;
        break;
    case "large-thickness":
        v = largeThickness;
        break;
    default:
        v = smallThickness;
}

pencilThickness = thickness;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = v;
```

I change the value of smallThickness, and call this block of code again.

Comment: I am really new to javascript, so please explain in simple words. I will be really thankful.

Comment: whats the error? what's the value you change in v?

Comment: i set it to v = 12

Comment: And a lot of weird things start to happen.

Comment: Hello, could you please add some more code so we know how to help you? :) Maybe a demo too.

Comment: I did add my function.

Comment: what's the value of `smallThickness`, `mediumThickness`, `largeThickness` make your variables clear so we can help you

Comment: also, provide an error message. "A lot of weird things start to happen" is not a valid error we can look at

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen you did not add "your function", you added a small piece of code. You did not show where the variable "thickness" comes from, for example.